# JSColor Picker is "underneeth" FancyBox / FeatherLight lightbox

Tags: jscolor

I've downloaded the latest JSColor (version 2.05) and i seem to have a problem regarding using it inside a lightbox (like FancyBox or FeatherLight).

When i click on the input textbox (which has the class of JSColor), I'm expecting to see the color picker, but it is opened underneeth the lightbox, and therefore we can't see him (it is like.. the lightbox is above it).

Any idea what can i do to make it visiable above all the windows / lightboxes?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the net, it appears that i needed to adjust the z-index of the FancyBox and of the ColorPicker. After supplying higher z-index for the color picker? => it became visible above the FancyBox.